# SearchBar overlaps navigation item title

Tags: ios, swift, layout, navigationbar, searchbar

I need to achieve the following result:

[image]

This is how it looks initially:

[image]

When I tap inside my `searchBar`, it goes up overlapping my `navigationItem.title`:

[image]

I tried `searchBarController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`, but it didn't work. Any solution please?

Comment: did you tried `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` ?

Comment: Yes, it makes the title large, but doesn't prevent hiding it when search bar is tapped

Answer (score 0):

I had my `searchBar` inside `tableView`. I fixed it by setting its top constraint to:

```
make.top.equalToSuperview()
```

instead of:

```
make.top.equalTo(safeAreaLayoutGuide)
```

And it also wouldn't work without:

```
navigationItem.searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

inside `viewDidLoad()` in my `ViewController`.